# System.IO.FileLoadException on executable after publish

Tags: c#, winforms, exception, executable

I'm having an issue I've never encountered before and Google wasn't too helpful.
I've published an executable for a windows forms app with Visual Studio 2022. The app crashes with the following message on the console:

```
Unhandled exception. System.IO.FileLoadException:
File name: 'System.Private.Uri, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
   at System.Windows.Forms.ThreadExceptionDialog..ctor(Exception t)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.OnThreadException(Exception t)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnThreadException(Exception e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, WM msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

However, it runs perfectly fine when I run it from within Visual Studio by hitting F5, as well as Run as different users, where the user is a local administrator on the machine. I can run other executables I've published just fine, however.

I tried wrapping everything in the entry point function in a try-catch block just to try and print out more information about the crash but the same message still appears.

Does anyone know why this is happening?
I didn't include any code as the Main function seems to not be running at all, but if you need any more info I will update.

Comment: What version of .net? Can you share a minimal example

Comment: Are you using a File Explorer.  Seen similar issues when the default folder doesn't exist or user doesn't have permission.  Set to default folder like c:\

Comment: Start by trying to replicate the issue by creating a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). If still unable to find the issue, post your minimal reproducible example that demonstrates the issue so others may run the code and also see the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue. Gonna leave this question up since it's a bit of an arcane case and may help someone else.

The exception was caused by an impersonation block left over from some previous testing I was doing. The credentials supplied to the Impersonate() call had administrative rights on the machine, but the account that ran the executable didn't.

I imagine this caused a security conflict and the executable crashed. If anyone has further insight, please feel free to comment.